# Unreadable bounty message

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Unreadable bounty message

[image: bounty message]

Comment: Jin has asked us to create one new question for each bug, rather than lumping them together. So it'd be better if you edit your question to be about the bounty message and remove the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed -- sorry about that.